# How to speed up DataFrame setting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have a  `list` of records whose format is `(index,column,value)`, and a `DataFrame` which is filled with `0`. For every record in `list`, I should do something like `df.loc[index,column]+=value`. This is a sample:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcd'),columns=list('abcd'),dtype=int)
df = df.fillna(0)
records = [('a','b',3),('a','b',5),('c','a',6)]
for index,column,value in records:
    df.loc[index,column] += value
```

And the expected output will be:

```
   a  b  c  d
a  0  8  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
c  6  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
```

However it runs too slowly since the `records` list is **TOO** big, and I wonder are there any methods to speed it up?

Update: It doesn't matter to use `int` index and column names instead of `str`, that is, the data structure also can be a `numpy.array` instead of a `DataFrame`. Therefore, the input `records` can be format like this:

```
records = [(0,1,3),(0,1,5),(3,1,6)]
```

And the expected output, of course, can be a `numpy.array` looks like:

```
[[0. 8. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: will you post how your expected ouput is looking?

Comment: @The Guy Of course, I've had the question editted. A perfect solution had been proposed for now. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Will there be multiple values in the list of records which add to the same element/location?

Comment: @AMC Yes, there is. In fact, it is the exactly the multiple values that make the issue difficult to solve.

Comment: @C.K. Are the column names strings, or are they simply integers/indices?

Comment: @AMC Well, they are strings actually, but also can be integers/indices. That doesn't matter.

Comment: @C.K. I was asking because I was wondering if a NumPy array might be a more appropriate data structure to use, although that may not be the case.

Comment: @AMC Oh, yes, you're right, maybe a NumPy array is a better data structure. Is there any good method then for this question since the data structure can be a NumPy array? Of course, even simple loop and setting should be faster than a `DataFrame` :D

Comment: @C.K. I'll give it a try right now, adapting the example data you shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207688/discussion-between-amc-and-c-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you can indeed use a NumPy array instead of a Pandas DataFrame. This particular solution takes advantage of [`numpy.ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html).

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((4, 4), dtype=int)

print(arr, end='\n\n')

idx_records = [(0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 5), (2, 0, 6)]

dim_1_idx, dim_2_ix, vals = zip(*idx_records)

print(dim_1_idx)
print(dim_2_ix)
print(vals, end='\n\n')

np.add.at(arr, (dim_1_idx, dim_2_ix), vals)

print(arr)
```

Ouput:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]

(0, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(3, 5, 6)

[[0 8 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [6 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Benchmarks by C.K. show this solution taking ~7.20 seconds, versus ~10.55 seconds for the Pandas method, on 10 million rows.

Comment: For the data like mine, use `numpy.array` is more faster, while if you must use `DataFrame`, jezrael's answer is perfect. By the way, many thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), so empty DataFrame is not necesary, only index and columns names:

```
records = [('a','b',3),('a','b',5),('c','a',6)]
r = list('abcd')
c = list('abcd')
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(records)
         .pivot_table(index=0, columns=1, values=2, aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(index=r, columns=c, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
1  a  b  c  d
0            
a  0  8  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
c  6  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: It worked, that's very useful for me! Thanks a lot!